# Maintenance on old Centos 5

Tags: centos, yum, software-updates

I have a dedicated application server running **Centos-5**. We all know that **Centos-5** is no longer supported and that the logical path is to upgrade, however in our case, the application is not ready to fly higher.

I manually moved the repositories to `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/...`, to avoid error messages when 'updating', knowing that this will not happen.

Are (security) updates for packages, that may or may not be Centos-5 dependent available? How and where can I reference them? For example: SAMBA, SSL (security) and Apache?

Comment: EOL generally means that there will be no forthcoming official patches or updated of any sort.  This usually comes _after_ an End of Support date upon which _only_ security and critical bugfix patches are forthcoming.  This gives you time, during the End of Support phase, to plan and implement your upgrade before End of Life.  With CentOS 5, full support ceased on 31 Jan 2014.

Comment: If you can run RHEL 5.11, you can buy extended life cycle support from Red Hat through 2020. https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-0561.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use case for Docker. You should look into spinning up a [CentOS 5](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/tree/2d0554464ae19f4fd70d1b540c8968dbe872797b/docker) container and then have your application in that. Only expose your app's ports to the world and you should be able to sleep a lot better at night.